for loop containing types.Sender sometimes does not leave and consumes 100% CPU
I have this simplified code here:
signer := types.LatestSignerForChainID(s.ethApiBackend.ChainConfig().ChainID)
log.Info("Before msg generation", "txsLen", len(txs))
msgs := make([]*vm.Msg, 0, len(txs))
        
for i := 0; i < len(txs); i++ {
    if i > lastIndex && txs[i].To() != nil {
        sender, _ := types.Sender(signer, &txs[i])
        ms := &vm.Msg{
            Sender:        vm.AccountRef(sender),
            ContractAddr:  *(txs[i].To()),
            CallDataBytes: txs[i].Data(),
            Gas:           uint64(txs[i].Gas()),
            GasPrice:      txs[i].GasPrice(),
            Value:         txs[i].Value(),
            TxHash:        txs[i].Hash(),
    }
    msgs = append(msgs, ms)
}

log.Info("After msg generation")

where txs is of types Transaction[]. lastIndex should not be relevant for the issue but its values can be between -1 and len(txs) - 1.
This code works in general, but sometimes (once in 5-10k times) I can see only the first log line "Before msg generation" but not the second one, and one CPU is running at 100%.
I cannot see a flaw in my loop in general, so somehow I suspect types.Sender to be the culprit here, but I can't see why as the logic behind is pretty straight and uses the sync/atomic module in the background.
Does anyone have a clue what could go wrong here?
EDIT: The issue happens within the types.Sender call. I found out using this version with added log info:
chainId := s.ethApiBackend.ChainConfig().ChainID
msgsToReprocess := make([]*vm.Msg, 0, len(txs)) 
lastMessageReprocessLog := "init"
abort := true   

go func() {
    time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
    if abort {
        log.Error("Processor ERROR - During msg conversion", "lenOfmsgsToReprocess", len(msgsToReprocess), "lastMessageReprocessLog", lastMessageReprocessLog)
        panic("panic abort!")
    }
}()

for i := 0; i < len(txs); i++ {
    if i > lastcachedIndex && txs[i].To() != nil {
        lastMessageReprocessLog = fmt.Sprintf("%d: 0 - txHash: %s", i, txs[i].Hash())
        signer := types.LatestSignerForChainID(chainId)
        lastMessageReprocessLog = fmt.Sprintf("%d: A - txHash: %s", i, txs[i].Hash())
        sender, _ := types.Sender(signer, &txs[i])
        lastMessageReprocessLog = fmt.Sprintf("%d: A-B - txHash: %s", i, txs[i].Hash())
        ms := &vm.Msg{
            Sender:        vm.AccountRef(sender),
            ContractAddr:  *(txs[i].To()),
            CallDataBytes: txs[i].Data(),
            Gas:           uint64(txs[i].Gas()),
            GasPrice:      txs[i].GasPrice(),
            Value:         txs[i].Value(),
            TxHash:        txs[i].Hash(),
        }
        lastMessageReprocessLog = fmt.Sprintf("%d: A-B-C - txHash: %s", i, txs[i].Hash())
        msgsToReprocess = append(msgsToReprocess, ms)
        lastMessageReprocessLog = fmt.Sprintf("%d: A-B-C-D - txHash: %s", i, txs[i].Hash())
    }
}
abort = false

Then, at the next panic, I saw this in my logs:
**ERROR[04-30|21:03:32.606] Processor ERROR - During msg conversion  lenOfmsgsToReprocess=9 lastMessageReprocessLog="9: A - txHash: 0x..."
panic: panic abort!**

The lenght of txs was 24, so it happened in the middle of processing the slice at index 9.
The tx was this here

Please see my answer below! As there's no reproducible source in your question, I cannot check whether my suggestion is true, but please give it a try. :)

Can you share the full "A - txHash: 0x...." log?

Hm what do you mean with whole log? It is just this log line which is relevant, because it shows what was written last when the program got stuck for a second, then my timing function intentionally panicked.the loop should normally take a few microseconds. It did not write the next line containing "A-B" so it was still inside the types.Sender call.

can you share the full txs[i].Hash() which was the last txHash being processed before the function panicked? That is what I mean :)

Check my latest edit

I believe the culprit might be the append(msgs, ms) when the condition if i > lastIndex && txs[i].To() != nil { evaluates as false.
Then the ms object of the vm.Msg structure type is not created, and that might make the memory panic.
The solution: Maybe you can change this line below... (*Where I believe you made a type when pasting it here on StackExchange — the closing } is missing in the struct instatiation.
for i := 0; i < len(txs); i++ {
if i > lastIndex && txs[i].To() != nil {
        sender, _ := types.Sender(signer, &txs[i])
        ms := &vm.Msg{
            Sender:        vm.AccountRef(sender),
            ContractAddr:  *(txs[i].To()),
            CallDataBytes: txs[i].Data(),
            Gas:           uint64(txs[i].Gas()),
            GasPrice:      txs[i].GasPrice(),
            Value:         txs[i].Value(),
            TxHash:        txs[i].Hash(),
    }
    }
    msgs = append(msgs, ms)
}

TO THIS below ?
for i := 0; i < len(txs); i++ {
if i > lastIndex && txs[i].To() != nil {
        sender, _ := types.Sender(signer, &txs[i])
        ms := &vm.Msg{
            Sender:        vm.AccountRef(sender),
            ContractAddr:  *(txs[i].To()),
            CallDataBytes: txs[i].Data(),
            Gas:           uint64(txs[i].Gas()),
            GasPrice:      txs[i].GasPrice(),
            Value:         txs[i].Value(),
            TxHash:        txs[i].Hash(),
    }
    
    msgs = append(msgs, ms)

    }
}


Many thanks for your thoughts, but you were right and i am sorry, I made exactly that typo. the msg append is actually there where your suggested code has it.
In the meantime I got closer to the issue, I will edit my post soon.

@flo Aah, ok! :)

I'll take a look at your edited post
